# Have any serial killers created puzzles that would free the victim if solved?

Tags: crime

One of the most common movie tropes is that of the serial killer who creates some kind of puzzle, trials, or other challenge that would free the victim if completed. It makes for an instantly dramatic movie or television plot, I have yet to hear of any cases that actually occurred outside of the silver screen.

Some serial killers, such as the infamous Zodiac Killer, used ciphered messages to taunt the police and media. As far as I can tell, the messages did not promise the freedom of his captives if they were decoded.

In a similar vein, the [Death of Brian Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Brian_Wells) came close to this. He had a bomb collar attached and was promised his freedom if he successfully robbed a bank and solved a treasure-hunt-style series of clues. I don't believe this qualifies as consensus of whether or not the perpetrators were serial killers is mixed, and the treasure hunt itself was unwinnable.

Have any serial killers created puzzles with deadly stakes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a history question.

Comment: What stack do you think would be more suitable to host this question?

Comment: @PausePause Horror novels, psychology, crime

Comment: This question seems legitimate to me. Why can't we have crime history?

Comment: @Jos Is there a crime stack?

Comment: @PausePause google it.

Comment: "Google it" can be said for any question in any Stack Exchange site or elsewhere, even the most interesting and in topic. Why is it a closing reason for this particular question.

Comment: Don't love this question, it borders on prurient and takes inspiration from the kind of crime dramas which glorify the killers and ignore their victims. However I'm voting to reopen it because similar criticisms could be leveled at many (not all) of the war related questions on this stack, and the querent made some effort to research it.